# Bind mediaelement to viewmodel

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro, mediaelement

I´m working on a big project in wpf that uses Caliburn Micro.
I have done a view that should view a movie. 
I´m trying to bind MediaElement Source to my file that I have in my ViewModel.

My View looks like this:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ContentControl cb:View.Model="{Binding}" />
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </controls:ExtendedTreeView>
    <MediaElement Source="media" Visibility="{Binding IsIndexVisible, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolToHiddenConverter}}" />
```

And in my viewmodel:

```
  public override void NavigateEnter()
    {
        //base.NavigateEnter();

        if (CanExpand)
        {
            base.Expand();
            return;
        }

        if (SelectedItem == null) return;

            var media = new MediaElement();

            media.LoadedBehavior = MediaState.Manual;
            media.Source = new Uri(@"C:/Users/v80770/Desktop/Movies/ATTV_bog.mpg");
            media.Play();
     }

            private Uri _mediaUri;
        public Uri MediaUri
        {
            get
            {
                return _mediaUri;
            }
            set
            {
                _mediaUri = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MediaUri);
            }
        }

  public override void NavigateEnter()
        {
            //base.NavigateEnter();

            if (CanExpand)
            {
                base.Expand();
                return;
            }

            if (SelectedItem == null) return;

            var test = (@"C:/Users/v80770/Desktop/Movies/ATTV_bog.mpg");
            var mediauri = new Uri(test);
            _mediaUri = mediauri;

            IsIndexVisible = false;
        }
```

But when I start my project nothing shows at all.

Comment: `ms-appx://` is not a valid URI scheme in a WPF application.

Comment: I removed that but still blank view

Comment: `var media = new MediaElement();` creates a new MediaElement. Besides that you should not create UI elements in a view model, it is of course not the one declared in the XAML of your view.

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: You have to set the property, not the backing field: `MediaUri = new Uri(test);`

Comment: Thanks Clemens, that solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the Uri as Source for Media Element. The Source Dependency Property expects type of Uri. You can verify it [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/MediaElement.cs).

```
<MediaElement Source="{Binding MediaUri}" />
```

Where MediaUri is defined as

```
public Uri MediaUri {get;set; }
```

Comment: Okej, and then I add the sourcefile to MediaUri?

Comment: @Emma yes. thats right. You can assign the file path to MediaUri (  new Uri(path)) )

Comment: Why this doesn't work for me?